# Inscribed circles problem

Tags: geometry

"The center of an inscribed circle of triangle ABC is **symmetric through side
AB to the center of the circumscribed circle**. Find the angles of triangle
ABC."

I don't understand what ***symmetric through side AB to the center of the circumscribed circle*** mean ?,how to draw the shape ?!

Comment: Maybe it means "to the same distance from AB as..."

Comment: No, @DonAntonio, it means that that the incenter is the reflection of the circumcenter across $AB$, that is $AB$ is the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining incenter and circumcenter.

Comment: Yes, and easy to show that $OI$ is a perpendicular bisector of $AB$, which ends the solution.

Comment: Yes, @MichaelRozenberg, the problem is pretty easy once one understands what it says. The angles are $\frac{\pi}{5},\ \frac{\pi}{5}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{5}$.

Comment: @AnubhabGhosal ...and thus both centers are at the same distance from $\;AB\;$ ...:) But yes: being AB part of the perp. bisector of the segment $\;AB\;$ is a stronger condition. Thank you